# Google app invites on iOS deep link only opens app store

Tags: ios, deep-linking, google-app-invites

I am working on adding Google App Invites deep linking to an iOS app and I followed all the steps for [Adding App invites to iOS](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/ios/guides/app) but the deep link just opens the app store to my app page even if the app is installed.
To recap, I...

- Installed the Cocoapod
- Generated and added the config file using the appropriate app store ID and bundle ID
- Included the code for `application:openURL:`... and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
- Added the URL Scheme for google and inputted the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID`

I'm not sure how to debug this considering I did all that Google told me to do. Their only help link on the Google Developers site was to Stack Overflow. Has anyone tried implementing these deep links on iOS and succeeded?

EDIT: This was done using iOS 8.x. @Caio pointed out the problem still persists on iOS 9 but not on iOS 7.x.

Comment: I have the same issue on iOS 9.x. It seems to work fine on iOS 7.x. I'm pretty sure thats Google problem on their SDK.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion on iOS 8.x.

Comment: this issue is not fixed, yet?

Comment: It was decided to not use Google app invites so I don't know.

Comment: Today I found the solution about this.

Answer (score 0):

We need to set the value "applinks:{your_app_link}.app.goo.gl" to Associated Domains on Capabilities tab of Xcode.